# Cable head is too small

Tags: shifting, cable

when I came to change the shifting (gear) cable on my claude butler bike I found that the original cable has a slightly bigger head(nipple) than the replacement cables I have-3.9mm compared to 3.5mm and consequently will not work-wtf
The mech is shimano v brake

Comment: You have Campagnolo compatible cables. They have slightly smaller heads. How does it not work? Does the smaller head slip through?

Comment: The ones I have are the same as those that are widely available-its the original one that is slightly bigger.Yes it slips out and wont hook on

Comment: In my opinion it makes a lot of sense to make generic cables compatible with all shifters out there. Looks like Shimano figured out a way to make their shifters non-compatible with third party cables then.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you've got Campagnolo-sized shifter ends.  The difference is subtle but definite.

[image: From https://bike.bikegremlin.com/8548/cable-housing-standards/]
Left is Shimano, Right is Campagnolo.

Not sure how you're measuring, using a ruler might explain the difference. The common-quoted diameters are

```
Shimano shifter end barrel diameter: 0.173" (4.39 mm)
Campag shifter end barrel diameter:  0.159" (4.04 mm)
```

Generally speaking, campagnolo stuff is more expensive because it is less common, because it is more expensive (loop!)  These shouldn't cost more than a couple of dollars each.